# Gorilla sessions not working on heroku

Tags: heroku, go, cookies, gorilla, beego

Hello I am using beego to create an API, and I am using gorillla for the session as I had problems with beego's session. Now this is working well on localhost but cookies are not sent on the deployed version on heroku.
Here is how I set the cookies in a controller:

```
session, _ := store.Get(c.Ctx.Request, "session") // c is the controller
session.Values["id"] = user.Id
```

Comment: Start by not omitting the error returned by `store.Get()`.  What is the returned error?

Comment: This is just an example.
The first endpoint I test with have error checking and no errors are printed.

Comment: Here is the full code
https://pastebin.com/GNiggVDt

Comment: I think this may be your problem:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-sessions